# Fetch the current page name in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-community

I created some pages with a hierarchy like Home(with child pages), About US, Contact, and so on. How can I fetch the current page in lwc template?

Are there ways to fetch all the available pages in the community using the same template? Or is there any API object for the page name that I can pass?

My requirement is similar to the breadcrumbs and found the out-of-the-box breadcrumbs component, but I am not sure how to map the settings for the pages instead of showing it for the article, feed, and topics.

Thanks in advance!